# Unable to load XML file in windows app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am trying to load an xml file in windows app and not able to do it.

The actual path of the file is `C:\Users\Desktop\Apps\Panel\Panel\Info.xml` and when I try to get them using the below mentioned code, it gives this error `Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Desktop\Apps\Panel\Panel\bin\Debug\Info.xml'.`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Info.xml");
```

Which means `\bin\Debug\` is added to the path additionally. Could anyone tell me how it got added and can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the file is located in your project, not in your Debug directory. Write it this way.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../../UserLoginInfo.xml");
```

If you want to work your way click properties on `UserLoginInfo.xml` in your project and select `Copy to output directory`

\bin\Debug\ is added because this is the directory where your app is started.